# Configuring WIX project to remove control panel options

Tags: wix

I am using Wix for create MSI packages.I have successfully created the project and its working fine. But i have challenge that I need to remove the `Repair` and `Change` functionality from my msi, means I need only the `uninstall` option for my msi. But currently I am unable to do so. I googled a lot and search every piece of tutorials, but didnt find any solution. Can anyone help me to Configuring WIX project to remove control panel options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control these kind of functionality by using the `ARP`-properties of Windows Installer, where `ARP` stands for **A**dd-or-**R**emove-**P**rograms.
In your specific case set the [`ARPNOREPAIR`-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367592(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ARPNOMODIFY`-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367590(v=vs.85).aspx)properties to `1`. That should do the trick.